# Apache Beam code to write output in ORC format

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io, orc

I am new to apache beam, and i have a use case where I need to write a java streaming code to read from a KafkaTopic (from which i extract some CustomObject.class) and output the entries to hdfs in ORC format.
I see there no ORC IO connector. Is it possible to write the results in ORC format using HadoopFormatIO connector? Is yes, can you please help me with this? The documentation for HadoopFormatIO connector in beam is not so clear to me.

Comment: Not sure this is helpful: https://github.com/sabhyankar/hadoop-inputformat-io-beam-example although it is for read.

Comment: Is there any developments underway to support this because the current HadoopFormatIO approach is tedious to work with. Its a well used columnar format.